# need to get entity key to delete entity

Tags: google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to delete an entity from the Datastore using a link in html.  I understand that in order to do this, I need to have the entity's key so that I know which entity to "pair" the delete link with, so to speak.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this...

Here is my html file that shows all of the cars in the database:

```
{% if cars|length > 0 %}
        {% for c in cars %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ c.make }}</td>
                <td>{{ c.model }}</td>
                <td>{{ c.year }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% for i in c.color %}
                        {{ i }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
                <td>{{ c.condition }}</td>
                <td>{{ c.date }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/view_cars/{{ c.key().id() }}">Delete Car</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

Here is the python file:

```
class AddCarHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    template_variables = {}

    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(self.template_variables))

        action = self.request.get('action')

        #if the user adds a car
        if action == 'add_car':
            c = car_database.Car()

            c.make = self.request.get('car-make')
            c.model = self.request.get('car-model')
            c.year = self.request.get('car-year')
            c.color = self.request.get_all('car-color')
            c.condition = self.request.get('car-condition')
            c.date = self.request.get('car-date')

            car_key = c.put()

class ViewCarHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    template_variables = {}

    def get(self):
        car = car_database.Car()
        #ndb query
        self.template_variables['cars'] = [{'make':x.make, 'model':x.model, 'year':x.year, 'color':x.color, 'condition':x.condition, 'date':x.date} for x in    car_database.Car.query().fetch()]
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/view_cars.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(self.template_variables))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key of an entity (which, say, is obtained through a query) like this:

```
entity_key = entity.key
```

Note: this only works *after* the entity was saved into the DB, not before (i.e. `entity.put()` was called at least once).

To pass the key between the python code and URLs or HTML code, from [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities), you can use a key's url string or a pre-computed deletion url based on that string, passed, for example, in `self.template_variables['cars']`:

> You can also use an entity's key to obtain an encoded string suitable
>   for embedding in a URL:
>
> ```
> url_string = sandy_key.urlsafe()
> ```
>
> This produces a result like agVoZWxsb3IPCxIHQWNjb3VudBiZiwIM which can
>   later be used to reconstruct the key and retrieve the original entity:
>
> ```
> sandy_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=url_string)
> sandy = sandy_key.get()
> ```

You'll need to add a handler for such deletion url, in which you'd reconstruct the key as quoted above, then call:

```
entity_key.delete()
```