# Default value for ndb.KeyProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python

I have these two models:

```
#################
### Usergroup ###
#################

class Usergroup(ndb.Model):
    group_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = False, required = True)
    is_admin_group = ndb.BooleanProperty(indexed = False, required = False, default = False)

############
### User ###
############

class User(ndb.Model):
    fb_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True, required = True)
    fb_access_token = ndb.TextProperty(indexed = False, required = True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = True, required = True)
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = False, required = True)
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = False, required = True)
    gender = ndb.StringProperty(indexed = False)
    group_key = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed = False, required = False, kind = Usergroup, default = ndb.Key(Usergroup, 'member'))
    join_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed = True, auto_now_add = True)
    last_login = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed = True, auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)

@app.route('/user/login', methods=['POST'])
def user_login():
    me = exchange_token_me(request.form['accessToken'])
    if me is not False:
        user = user_find_or_register(me)
        if user is not None:
            register_session(user)
            return 'success'
    return 'error'

def user_find_or_register(user):
    qry = User.query(User.fb_id == user['id'])
    existing_user = qry.get()

    if existing_user is not None:
        existing_user.fb_access_token = user['access_token']
        existing_user.fb_id = user['id']
        existing_user.email = user['email']
        existing_user.last_login = datetime.datetime.now()
        existing_user.put()
        return existing_user

    new_user = User()
    new_user.fb_id = user['id']
    new_user.fb_access_token = user['access_token']
    new_user.email = user['email']
    new_user.first_name = user['first_name']
    new_user.last_name = user['last_name']
    new_user.gender = user['gender']
    new_user.last_login = datetime.datetime.now()
    #new_user.group_key = ndb.key(Usergroup, 'member')

    key = new_user.put()
    saved_user = key.get()
    #key.delete() # DEBUG

    if saved_user is not None:
        return saved_user

def register_session(user):
    session['fb_id'] = user.fb_id
    session['first_name'] = user.first_name
    session['last_name'] = user.last_name
    session['group_key'] = user.group_key
    session['loggedin'] = True
```

The Usergroup model has a small unique string as entity key. There is already a Usergroup whose key is 'member'

Whenever we create/save a user, it should use the key to the 'member' usergroup, but we get this error instead:

TypeError: Key('Usergroup', 'member') is not JSON serializable

Traceback:

```
ERROR    2016-10-18 14:32:40,572 app.py:1587] Exception on /user/login [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 1643, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 1864, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 926, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/sessions.py", line 359, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/itsdangerous.py", line 565, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/itsdangerous.py", line 847, in dump_payload
    json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/itsdangerous.py", line 550, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
    return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/json.py", line 126, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 209, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/json.py", line 83, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Key('Usergroup', 'member') is not JSON serializable
ERROR    2016-10-18 14:32:40,593 main.py:178] An error occurred during a request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 1643, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 1864, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 926, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/sessions.py", line 359, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/itsdangerous.py", line 565, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/itsdangerous.py", line 847, in dump_payload
    json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/itsdangerous.py", line 550, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
    return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/json.py", line 126, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 209, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/json.py", line 83, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Key('Usergroup', 'member') is not JSON serializable
INFO     2016-10-18 14:32:40,610 module.py:788] default: "POST /user/login HTTP/1.1" 500 27
```

UPDATE:
After Dan has spotted the problem, the solution is in the following function:

```
def register_session(user):
    session['fb_id'] = user.fb_id
    session['first_name'] = user.first_name
    session['last_name'] = user.last_name
    session['group_key'] = user.group_key.id() # Thanks Dan
    session['loggedin'] = True
```

Comment: Storing the key ID is OK, too, but you can do it directly with `session['group_key'] = user.group_key.id()` - saving an unnecessary datastore `get()` operation.

Comment: Indeed, I have just used this in a template too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, a quick test with your code as `models.py` shows this to be working just fine, at least on the development server:

```
    from models import User

    user = User(email='email', username='username')
    user.put()
```

produced:

[image]

This worked without even having a `Usergroup` entity - a key can exist without a matching entity. Of course, trying to follow the link to the Usergroup in the datastore viewer fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/admin_request_handler.py", line 96, in dispatch
    super(AdminRequestHandler, self).dispatch()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine_1.9.40/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/datastore_viewer.py", line 741, in get
    entities = [datastore.Get(entity_key)]
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 671, in Get
    return GetAsync(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1717, in __get_hook
    entities = extra_hook(entities)
  File "/home/usr_local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 640, in local_extra_hook
    raise datastore_errors.EntityNotFoundError()
EntityNotFoundError
```

So you might want to show your actual code creating the entity and the full traceback, something else may be going on.

Your traceback indicates that the problem is **not** with creating the entity, but with saving your session:

```
File "/var/www/mywebsite/public_html/lib/flask/app.py", line 926, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
```

It appears you included in the session content the key object (possibly by including the entire `User` entity?), which is what causes the failure. For that purpose keys need to be serialized and you can use `key.urlsafe()` for that. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835074/4495081

If indeed you included the entire `User` entity in the session you can just include its urlsafe key instead.

Yup, this is the source of your problem:

```
session['group_key'] = user.group_key
```

change it to:

```
session['group_key'] = user.group_key.urlsafe()
```

And you'll retrieve it like this:

```
urlsafe_key = session.get('group_key')
if urlsafe_key:
    group_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlsafe_key)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have updated my question with more code and Traceback

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, indeed it's in the register_session function. I have added it to the question too.

Comment: I have included the key instead, and I can use Usergroup.get_by_id(session.get('group_key')) to get the usergroup. Thanks again Dan